# .net mvc email as username returning error - InvalidProviderUserKey

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, createuser

I have a .Net MVC application that I am trying to use an email address as the username. I implemented the logic from [this article](http://www.aspcode.net/CreateUserWizard-using-email-as-username.aspx) where the username is masked as the email. However, when I try to call

```
private readonly MembershipProvider _provider;
MembershipCreateStatus status;
_provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email, null, null, true, false, out status);
```

where the username is "email@email.com", the status always returns as **InvalidProviderUserKey**. If i use a standard username (without the @), it works fine. I tried searching for a solution but i can really find an explanation of InvalidProviderUserKey anywhere.

I was wondering if someone has run into this problem before or might be able to offer an explanation of why this scenario would be returning this specific status. Thanks in advance for any help.

**UPDATE**

I used Guid.NewGuid for the ProviderUserKey and it worked.

```
_provider.CreateUser(userName, password, email,null, null, true, Guid.NewGuid(), out status);
```

Thank you Daniel A. White for your help. The article link that you provided was what I needed to understand it.

Comment: what is your membership provider?

Comment: It is the default membership provider, **public abstract class MembershipProvider : ProviderBase**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you pass something to `providerUserKey`, not just `false`.

> `providerUserKey` Type: `System.Object`
>   The unique identifier from the
>   membership data source for the user.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipprovider.createuser.aspx